# Problems with python asyncore working with AF_UNIX sockets

Tags: python, sockets, asyncore, unix-socket

I have some problems using asyncore with AF_UNIX sockets. This code

```
import asyncore, socket, os
class testselect(asyncore.dispatcher):

    path = '/tmp/mysocket'

    def __init__(self):

        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)

        self.create_socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.bind(self.path)
        self.buffer = 'buffer'

    def handle_connect(self):

        print 'handle_connect'
        pass

    def handle_close(self):
        print 'handle_close'
        if os.path.exists(self.path)       
             os.remove(self.path)
        self.close()

    def handle_read(self):
        print 'handle_read'
        print self.recv(8192)

    def writable(self):
        print 'writable'
        return (len(self.buffer) > 0)

    def handle_write(self):
        print 'handle_write'
        sent = self.send(self.buffer)
        self.buffer = self.buffer[sent:]


    client = testselect()
    asyncore.loop()
```

If i execute the code

```
 $ python select_prova.py
 writable
 handle_connect
 handle_write
 handle_close
 $
```

It quits immediatly, and doesn't wait for read and write. If i change code to force writable() method to return always `False`, it wait correctly for input and i can communicate with socat like this

```
 $ socat readline UNIX:/tmp/mysocket
```

But only for reading (write logically doesn't works because writable() returns `False`). Are there error in my code or I can't manage AF_UNIX sockets with asyncore/select() ?

Comment: This is a really interesting difficulty you're having.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note** As the other answer points out, when you send a datagram you need to specify the receiver. As it stands, your `testselect` class looks more like a client than a server.

Review some of these [`asyncore examples`](http://effbot.org/librarybook/asyncore.htm) to find a server pattern you can copy. The `TimeChannel` example is closer to what you want -- change `socket.AF_INET` to `socket.AF_UNIX` and use a socket path for the bind address to have it use a UNIX domain socket.

---

You're setting `socket.SOCK_DGRAM` which usually indicates creation of a UDP INET socket. Unix domain sockets are a form of IPC. You should change it to `socket.SOCK_STREAM`, call `self.listen([backlog])`, implement `handle_accept()`, etc.

If you did intend to use SOCK_DGRAM with AF_UNIX, the reason your server exits is that it is indicating `writable` as soon as it's started, which causes `handle_write` to run, sending the packet containing `'buffer'` immediately.

If you want your server to wait until it's received a packet before replying, set the buffer in `handle_connect` or `handle_read`:

```
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.buffer = ''

    def handle_connect(self):
        self.buffer = 'buffer'
```

Now when you start your server it'll wait until it receives a packet from `socat`.

---

I've rewritten your example to work more like you indend:

```
import asyncore, socket, os

class testselect(asyncore.dispatcher):

    path = '/tmp/mysocket'

    def __init__(self):
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
        self.create_socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.set_reuse_addr()
        self.bind(self.path)
        self.listen(5)

    def handle_accept(self):
        client = self.accept()
        if client is None:
            pass
        else:
            handler = testhandler(*client)

class testhandler(asyncore.dispatcher_with_send):

    def __init__(self, sock, addr):
        asyncore.dispatcher_with_send.__init__(self, sock)
        self.addr = addr
        self.buffer = 'greetings'

    def handle_read(self):
        print self.recv(8192)

    def writable(self):
        return (len(self.buffer) > 0)

    def handle_write(self):
        self.send(self.buffer)
        self.buffer = ''

    def handle_close(self):
        self.close()

server = testselect()
try:
    asyncore.loop()
finally:
    if os.path.exists(testselect.path):
        os.unlink(testselect.path)
```

Comment: There is no TCP or UDP here, there is only Zuul.  Err...  TCP and UDP are things on top of the IP protocol.  AF_UNIX sockets do not speak IP.  They are more akin to pipes.

Comment: Yeah, said UDP when I meant DGRAM. Shouldn't write faster than I think.

Answer (score 1):

Your difficulty can be boiled down to the fact you're using SOCK_DGRAM. From what I can tell, you basically cannot effectively handle SOCK_DGRAM sockets with asyncore (no `recvfrom` or `sendto`). Additionally, socat does not seem to have a way to work with SOCK_DGRAM UNIX domain sockets.

SOCK_DGRAM sockets have no real notion of a connection, so they will always register as writeable in a select call. But when you actually do the `write` it will fail because you're not supplying a destination address.

The other answer has terminology wrong, but is basically correct. You need to use a SOCK_STREAM socket here.